# Persisting TextBox text in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I am having a bit of trouble importing/exporting data to and from an excel workbook. For example I have a form with 3 textboxes.

I have setup a simple Excel sheet with cells A1, A2 and A3 completed.  When I run the debug only the first 2 boxes are populated with the Excel data.

Also, when I alter the value in the textbox it doesn't save back to the original spreadsheet!?!  When I try to open the spreadsheet to see if the save has taken place a read only notification comes up...but I still want to be able to alter the original sheet so that new data is imported on application launch!

I have pasted the code below...am I doing something seriously wrong?

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
    Dim objWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\HP\desktop\Book2.xls")
        objWorksheet = CType(objWorkbook.Worksheets.Item("Sheet1"), Excel.Worksheet)
        TextBox1.Text = objWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).text
        TextBox2.Text = objWorksheet.Cells(2, 1).text
        TextBox3.Text = objWorksheet.Cells(3, 1).text
    End Sub

  Private Sub Command1_Click()
        objWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = TextBox1.Text
        objWorksheet.Cells(2, 3).Value = TextBox2.Text
        objWorksheet.Cells(3, 3).Value = TextBox3.Text
    End Sub

   Private Sub Command2_Click()
        objExcel.Application.Quit()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Command3_Click()
        objExcel.SaveAs("C:\Users\HP\desktop\Book2.xls")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Does the code above compile? It shouldnt just look at this line     TextBox3.Text = objWorksheet.celss(3, 1).text

Comment: Thanks Mattias, that was a typo that I hadn't noticed that was preventing txtbox 3 from populating....do you have any ideas about why i can't seem to write back to excel and also reopen the original spreadsheet to alter the cell content? Sorry for all the questions, i'm very new to VB and am still finding my way.  Thanks again H

Comment: What are u using to read the excel what library do you import to use Excel.Workbook for example?

Comment: i've used the Properties>add referrence>com>microsoft excel10.0 object library

Answer (score 0):

The line that sets the textbox3 is miss typed TextBox3.Text = objWorksheet.celss(3, 1).text

Try to replace your code with this code. If it still complains on the fileprotection try it on a new file because the old file is still locked.
    Public Class Form1

```
Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim objWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim objWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\Bok3.xlsx")

    objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets.Item("Sheet1")

    TextBox1.Text = objWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).text
    TextBox2.Text = objWorksheet.Cells(2, 1).text
    TextBox3.Text = objWorksheet.Cells(3, 1).text
    objExcel.Workbooks.Close()
    objExcel.Application.Quit()

End Sub

Private Sub Command1()
    objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\Bok3.xlsx")

    objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets.Item("Sheet1")


    objWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = TextBox1.Text
    objWorksheet.Cells(2, 1).Value = TextBox2.Text
    objWorksheet.Cells(3, 1).Value = TextBox3.Text

    objWorkbook.Save()
    objExcel.Workbooks.Close()
    objExcel.Application.Quit()

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I've tried that with no luck i'm afraid...a new error message has also now popped up saying that New cannot be used as an interface (line 3) In addition the app is now returning no values at all from the excel workbook. I have amended the code in my original question to show what I now have Thank again for your help H

Comment: I have updated my answer and tried the code myself and it works so I hope it helps you out.

Comment: Thanks Mattias....I'm afraid I am still at a complete loss here though.  The app is reading the data OK but for some reason as soon as the file path for the excel sheet is included in the line ' objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Public\Book2.xls") the file automatically becomes read only.  I have checke dthe file properties and they are not set to read only so i'm not really sure what is going on?   I have created a new file twice now each with different designations but the same thing keeps happening.  Thank you so much for your help with this, I really appreciate it   H

Comment: The file was not closed after the read thats why it still was read only. Code for closing added and if you take a new blank file it will work.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Mattias...it' still not writing to the excel file for some reason despite copying your code word for word but....I think i'll leave you in peace now and try to come up with anoher solution.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use a standard API call to end the process, thus unlocking the Excel file.

If you use `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objComObject)` the process still seems to remain until the program is closed, at which time the Excel Process is terminated and the file can be opened without being "Read-Only."

Here is a way to do it:

```
Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Int32, ByVal wMsg As Int32, _
ByVal wParam As Int32, ByVal lParam As Int32) As Int32
    Const WM_QUIT = &H12
```

In your code, after saving and quiting, call the PostMessage

```
PostMessage(objExcel.Hwnd, WM_QUIT, 0, 0)
```

The process will end and thus release the lock. I have had this problem before and there is an insane amount of stuff on it all over the internet. Some versions of the `ReleaseComObject` work but the only seem to work on versions of Excel later than XP and they don't seem to work well on versions of XP. Doesn't make a ton of sense, but the only thing I seem to have found to work is this `PostMessage` declaration.

Good luck... you aren't the only one out there. Just search "excel.application process release" in Bing and you will be surprised what you find!!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work OK if you save the worksheet instead of the workbook. This assumes you only need to save the current worksheet.

```
Public Class Form1

Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim objWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim objWorkbook As Excel.Workbook

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\HP\desktop\Book2.xls")

    objWorksheet = CType(objWorkbook.Worksheets.Item("Sheet1"), Excel.Worksheet)

    TextBox1.Text = objWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).text
    TextBox2.Text = objWorksheet.Cells(2, 1).text
    TextBox3.Text = objWorksheet.Cells(3, 1).text
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click() Handles Button1.Click

    objWorksheet.Cells(1, 3).Value = TextBox1.Text
    objWorksheet.Cells(2, 3).Value = TextBox2.Text
    objWorksheet.Cells(3, 3).Value = TextBox3.Text

    objWorksheet.SaveAs("C:\Users\HP\desktop\Book2.xls")
    objExcel.Workbooks.Close()
    objExcel.Application.Quit()

End Sub

End Class
```